# Downloading all documents through the URL hack gives "This content pack is empty...and cannot be downloaded" error

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-experience, attachment, contentdocument

Based on some answers and google searching, I've understood that all content documents attached to a record can be downloaded if a url is with '/' separated content document IDs  formed as below :

```
https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/06AN0000002deibMAA/06AN00000030E6BMAU/06AN00000030E6pMAE/06AN00000030E6uMAE?
```

To create a button out of it, I've written a function :

```
public static List<Id> getContentDocumentLinks(Id loanId) {
        try {
            String baseUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
            List<ContentDocumentLink> contentDocumentLinks = [  SELECT Id, COntentdocumentId 
                                                                FROM  ContentDocumentLink 
                                                                WHERE LinkedEntityId = :loanId];
            List<Id> contentDocIds = new List<Id>();
            for (ContentDocumentLink cdl : contentDocumentLinks) {
                contentDocIds.add(cdl.Id);
            }
            String downloadUrl = baseUrl+'/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/'+String.join(contentDocIds,'/');
            System.debug('downloadUrl : '+downloadUrl);
            return contentDocIds;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.debug('Error : '+ex.getMessage() + ' --> '+ ex.getStackTraceString());
            throw new downloadDocsException(ex.getMessage());
        }
   }
```

But opening that url while i'm logged in as the administrator gives me error - This content pack is empty or contains only links and Google Docs, and cannot be downloaded.

[image]

How could this be fixed ??

Comment: so, are any of the ContentDocumentIds associated to the `loanId` a ContentDocument of type Link or GoogleDoc?  You may need to filter those out before adding to the URL string

Comment: All the documents have been uploaded manually through an LWC that uses lightning-file-upload

Answer (score 2):

I made a mistake in the code by adding the ContentDocumentLink's Id in the list instead of adding ContentDocumentLink.contentDocumentId.

Fixed code :

```
public static List<Id> getContentDocumentLinks(Id loanId) {
        try {
            String baseUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
            List<ContentDocumentLink> contentDocumentLinks = [  SELECT Id, COntentdocumentId 
                                                                FROM  ContentDocumentLink 
                                                                WHERE LinkedEntityId = :loanId];
            List<Id> contentDocIds = new List<Id>();
            for (ContentDocumentLink cdl : contentDocumentLinks) {
                contentDocIds.add(cdl.COntentdocumentId);   // Add contentdocumentId
            }
            String downloadUrl = baseUrl+'/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/'+String.join(contentDocIds,'/');
            System.debug('downloadUrl : '+downloadUrl);
            return contentDocIds;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.debug('Error : '+ex.getMessage() + ' --> '+ ex.getStackTraceString());
            throw new downloadDocsException(ex.getMessage());
        }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you!  Such a simple thing but this comment/answer helped me solve a problem I've been working on for days.